# Kill long running SQL query from grails application

Tags: java, oracle, grails, jakarta-ee

I may look stupid by asking this question - but i want to kill any questions that i have in my mind regarding this..

So.. the question is --

Can we abort/kill a `select` SQL from my **grails** application which is triggered from my application itself?

In layman terms -

- I have 'Search' and 'Stop' buttons on my screen

  - Action on search button will prepare a select SQL which will take quite sometime to execute and fetch results
  - I want to abort long running SQL (not just application stop waiting for result. It should abort the SQL process in the background) by clicking 'Stop' button

(My DB is Oracle)

Please help me clear this trash from my mind.

Comment: What have you coded so far? I ask because a GORM query executes within a transaction, which ends when the controller renders to the client. So are you somehow keeping the transaction open in the background?

Comment: Killing sessions is normally done at the database level.  It does not seem like a good practice to kill a session that runs too long.  How long is too long? Consider a pipelined procedure to return the first few results while the user is waiting for the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a query timeout. Grails uses Hibernate which implements JPA.

JPA2 persistence property "javax.persistence.query.timeout" allows you to set the timeout for a query (assuming the underlying JDBC driver supports it).

So add the following to the grails-app/conf/Config.groovy:

```
javax.persistence.query.timeout=9000
```

The value is in milliseconds, so that would be 9 seconds.